# Showing data and model predictions in one plot using Seaborn and Statsmodels

Tags: python, matplotlib, statsmodels, seaborn

Seaborn is a great package for doing some high-level plotting with pretty outputs. However, I'm struggling a little with using Seaborn to overlay both data and model predictions from an externally-fit model. In this example I am fitting models in Statsmodels that are too complex for Seaborn to do out-of-the-box, but I think the problem is more general (i.e. if I have model predictions and want to visualise both them and data using Seaborn).

Let's start with imports and a dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import patsy
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(12345)

# make a data frame with one continuous and two categorical variables:
df = pd.DataFrame({'x1': np.random.normal(size=100),
                     'x2': np.tile(np.array(['a', 'b']), 50),
                     'x3': np.repeat(np.array(['c', 'd']), 50)})

# create a design matrix using patsy:
X = patsy.dmatrix('x1 * x2 * x3', df)

# some random beta weights:
betas = np.random.normal(size=X.shape[1])

# create the response variable as the noisy linear combination of predictors:
df['y'] = np.inner(X, betas) + np.random.normal(size=100)
```

We fit a model in statsmodels containing all predictor variables and their interactions:

```
# fit a model with all interactions
fit = smf.ols('y ~ x1 * x2 * x3', df).fit()
print(fit.summary())
```

Since in this case we have all combinations of variables specified, and our model predictions are linear, it would suffice for plotting to add a new "predictions" column to the dataframe containing the model predictions. However, that's not very general (imagine our model is nonlinear and so we want our plots to show smooth curves), so instead I make a new dataframe with all combinations of predictors, then generate predictions:

```
# create a new dataframe of predictions, using pandas' expand grid:
def expand_grid(data_dict):
    """ A port of R's expand.grid function for use with Pandas dataframes.

    from http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html?highlight=expand%20grid

    """
    rows = itertools.product(*data_dict.values())
    return pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows, columns=data_dict.keys())


# build a new matrix with expand grid:

preds = expand_grid(
                {'x1': np.linspace(df['x1'].min(), df['x1'].max(), 2),
                 'x2': ['a', 'b'],
                 'x3': ['c', 'd']})
preds['yhat'] = fit.predict(preds)
```

The `preds` dataframe looks like this:

```
  x3        x1 x2      yhat
0  c -2.370232  a -1.555902
1  c -2.370232  b -2.307295
2  c  3.248944  a -1.555902
3  c  3.248944  b -2.307295
4  d -2.370232  a -1.609652
5  d -2.370232  b -2.837075
6  d  3.248944  a -1.609652
7  d  3.248944  b -2.837075
```

Since Seaborn plot commands (unlike `ggplot2` commands in R) appear to accept one *and only one* dataframe, we need to merge our predictions into the raw data:

```
# append to df:
merged = df.append(preds)
```

We can now plot the model predictions along with the data, with our continuous variable `x1` as the x-axis:

```
# plot using seaborn:
sns.set_style('white')
sns.set_context('talk')
g = sns.FacetGrid(merged, hue='x2', col='x3', size=5)
# use the `map` method to add stuff to the facetgrid axes:
g.map(plt.plot, "x1", "yhat")
g.map(plt.scatter, "x1", "y")
g.add_legend()
g.fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.3)
sns.despine(offset=10);
```

[image]

So far so good. Now imagine that we didn't measure the continuous variable `x1`, and we only know about the other two (categorical) variables (i.e., we have a 2x2 factorial design). **How can we plot the model predictions against data in this case?**

```
fit = smf.ols('y ~ x2 * x3', df).fit()
print(fit.summary())

preds = expand_grid(
                {'x2': ['a', 'b'],
                 'x3': ['c', 'd']})
preds['yhat'] = fit.predict(preds)
print(preds)

# append to df:
merged = df.append(preds)
```

Well, we can plot the model predictions using `sns.pointplot` or similar, like so:

```
# plot using seaborn:
g = sns.FacetGrid(merged, hue='x3', size=4)
g.map(sns.pointplot, 'x2', 'yhat')
g.add_legend();
sns.despine(offset=10);
```

[image]

Or the data using `sns.factorplot` like so:

```
g = sns.factorplot('x2', 'y', hue='x3', kind='point', data=merged)
sns.despine(offset=10);
g.savefig('tmp3.png')
```

[image]

But I do not see how to produce a plot similar to the first one (i.e. lines for model predictions using `plt.plot`, a scatter of points for data using `plt.scatter`). The reason is that the `x2` variable I'm trying to use as the x-axis is a string / object, so the pyplot commands don't know what to do with them.

Comment: Note that I recognise that the lines in the last plot are the same as the lines in the second plot (i.e. the model predictions are just lines between the means). This won't always be true, though, so I'm after a more general approach.

Comment: Also note that for some unknown reason, the legend in the second plot doesn't show the "c" and "d" cases, only the legend title. I don't know why.

Comment: You can pass any function to `FacetGrid.map` as long as it takes `x`, `y` positional arguments and plots onto the "currently" active axes. So you should be able to define a function that maps from your categories to [0, 1, 2, ...] and use that. Does that help?

Comment: Maybe another strategy would be to reformat your dataframe so that your data and model predictions are in the same column and then use a `hue` variable that indicates whether the points and traces are data or predictions. Using different markers and linestyles will help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I mention in my comments, there are two ways I would think about doing this.

The first is to define a function that does the fit and then plots and pass it to `FacetGrid.map`:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

def plot_good_tip(day, total_bill, **kws):

    expected_tip = (total_bill.groupby(day)
                              .mean()
                              .apply(lambda x: x * .2)
                              .reset_index(name="tip"))
    sns.pointplot(expected_tip.day, expected_tip.tip,
                  linestyles=["--"], markers=["D"])

g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="sex", size=5)
g.map(sns.pointplot, "day", "tip")
g.map(plot_good_tip, "day", "total_bill")
g.set_axis_labels("day", "tip")
```

[image]

The second is the compute the predicted values and then merge them into your DataFrame with an additional variable that identifies what is data and what is model:

```
tip_predict = (tips.groupby(["day", "sex"])
                   .total_bill
                   .mean()
                   .apply(lambda x: x * .2)
                   .reset_index(name="tip"))
tip_all = pd.concat(dict(data=tips[["day", "sex", "tip"]], model=tip_predict),
                    names=["kind"]).reset_index()

sns.factorplot("day", "tip", "kind", data=tip_all, col="sex",
               kind="point", linestyles=["-", "--"], markers=["o", "D"])
```

[image]